# Regular expression to match floats only

Tags: regex

I need to do a regular expression to match the floats only, what i got is the following  :

```
[\-\+]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?
```

But this match also the below 
123123132 , 
05/03/1994

I only need want to match the number with the decimal point

Comment: What do you mean with "floats only"? A decimal point is *required* for you?

Comment: yes i need the decimal point

Comment: Remove the last `?`, and use `^` and `$` anchors if needed.

Comment: Don't escape `-` and `+` inside brackets (`-` is not a range because it's at the beginning, `+` doesn't need escaping).  Change `*` to `+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct for your purpose.

It finds `123123132`, because the last part is optional. Removing the `?` solves that.

```
[-+]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)
```

With that adjustment, it might still find matches in strings like `.12/39/3239`, if you don't want that to happen, insert enforce matching over the complete string by inserting `^` and `$`:

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)$
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
([+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)
```

You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/iJ1gZ8/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regexp handling also existing **exponents**:

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AJCLSEVJY9dFDwTi)

Additionally you should force the hole string to be matched to avoid matchings within your date values.

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

By the way here is a nice tutorial about matching floating point numbers using regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html.